# Combining multiple departments of the same university in the institute field (LNCS)

Tags: lncs, paper

[image]

I want to combine multiple departments of the same university in the institute section. Please refer to the image provided. This will save a lot of space and be much more clear as well.

Please let me know what's the best way to go about doing this, as I currently have no idea.

I'm using the LNCS template.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.